# How can I access Moose attributes from class methods?

Tags: perl, oop, moose

Consider the following code:

```
package Test1;
use Moose; 

has 'something' => (
    is => 'rw',
    default => 'BLAH!'
);

sub printSomething {
    my ($self) = @_;
    ## What should I use here to get the value of something?
    print $self->something;
}

package Test2;

Test1->printSomething();
```

How can `printSomething` access `something`?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect a class method to *have* attributes it can access?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: How about a person class having a 'find' class method that uses the 'table' attribute to know which DB to query?

Comment: And how do you control it if you want the table attribute to be one thing for one call to find and something different for another call to find?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can't. You have to instantiate a `Test1` object in order for attribute defaults to be constructed. They don't hang out in the class.

If you want true class attributes in Moose, you can just write a method that closes over something and returns it:

```
{
    my $class_attr = 'BLAH!';
    sub something { 
        return $class_attr;
    }
}
```

Of course, then you have to do some more work to add setters and clearers and whatnot, if you need those. A better way is to use [MooseX::ClassAttribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aClassAttribute) like this:

```
package Test1;

use Moose;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;

class_has 'something' => ( 
    is       => 'rw',
    default  => 'BLAH!'
);
```

That has the advantage of making Moose aware of your class attribute, and adding in meta-introspection goodness automatically.